# How to sum the values for a specific key in json list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a list of dictionaries, where keys are: "country", "points", "price". I have 117000 rows. I need to group those by country and get the sum of points and sum of price for each country. There are 44 countries in my dataset.

I need a list of dictionaries in return.

`country_list = [{"Country": USA}, {"sum_points": 120}, {"sum_price": 200}], etc...`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Kinda stuck with this task...

Comment: is this a pandas DF?

Comment: I have it in JavaScript and pandas DF as well.

Comment: Can you post some code that you have already tried/written?

Comment: Groupby method of a pandas df is what you are looking for.

Comment: `df.groupby('Country').agg({'sum_points':'sum', 'sum_price':'sum'})` ?

Comment: That worked perfectly and gave me exactly what I was looking for. I have to find avg points for each country now. So let's say I have a df that I can convert to a dictionary to look like this:  ```{'country': USA, 'sum_points': 480488, 'sume_price': 116181.0}``` I have to add one more key that will have the number of specific country occurrence in my previous list of dictionaries in order to get the average for points and price. Any idea how to make that happen? Once I have this I think I can figure out how to implement avg function, maybe for loop for that purpose that will do basic calc. Ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
df.groupby(['Country']).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with pandas library,
but with only 117000 rows of data you can definitely brute-force this problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
import collections
####### generating random inputs ###############
# for this part of my code I randomly generated 117000 rows of mock data using a
# list of 44 random countries and with prices and points between 1-1000.
# I stored it in the variable "random_input"
countries = ["anistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Côte d'Ivoire", "Cabo Verde", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", ]

random_input = []
for i in range(117000):
    random_input.append({
        "Country": random.choice(countries),
        "points": random.randint(1,1000),
        "price": random.randint(1,1000)
        })

##################################################
#               actual computing                 #
##################################################

#For this part, I created two counters and iterated through the input to count
# the number of price and points grouped by each country

sum_points = collections.Counter()
sum_prices = collections.Counter()
for row in random_input:
    sum_points[row["Country"]] += row["points"]
    sum_prices[row["Country"]] += row["price"]


# Finally format the output as a list of dictionaries

country_lst = []
for country in sum_points.keys():
    country_lst.append({
            "Country": country,
            "sum_points": sum_points[country],
            "sum_prices": sum_prices[country],
            })
print(country_lst)
```

Comment: The discovery of `"anistan"` deserves an upvote.